# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/internet/ParseException

Tags: java, maven, email, jakarta-mail

I've seen this being asked before, but my case seems to be different. This happens when I run a junit on a standalone java program which retrieves emails from an smtp server via pop3.

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/internet/ParseException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at tideworks.edi.inboundemailhandler.EmailProcessorTest.fooTest(EmailProcessorTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
```

I've seen many questions and all of them say it is because it's trying to run an interface with no implementation from javaee. But I'm NOT using javaee, jboss, glassfish, etc. This program runs as a background daemon just with the JDK 1.7, no app server.

My POM:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>tideworks.edi</groupId>
   <artifactId>ediInboundEmailHandler</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <parent>
     <groupId>tideworks.edi</groupId>
     <artifactId>ediaas</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>

   <name>ediInboundEmailHandler</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>

   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.14.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>   
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <!-- slf4j for dbunit -->
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.6</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <!-- slf4j-log4j12 for dbunit -->
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easetech</groupId>
        <artifactId>easytest-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>tideworks.edi</groupId>
      <artifactId>ediaasDao</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>ediFileParser</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>ediaasDao</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

   </project>
```

EDIT

I add an screenshot with the dependencies loaded by maven. I don't see any javaee:
[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js50t.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Check that one of your dependencies isn't dragging in some other version of JavaMail or some javaee.jar file.

Also, note that you're using a **very old** version of JavaMail.  The current version is 1.5.6, get it [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

Comment: I have tried with different versions of javamail and still not working. This project has been working like a charm for 3 years with no need of updating it since then. I looked trough my dependencies and didn't find anything related to JEE. I edited my question with an screenshot of the dependencies loaded by maven.

Comment: [What's JEE](https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE)?  Are those the direct dependencies or does it also include the indirect dependencies?  You may have to look inside each of those jar files to see if one of them includes the javax.mail or com.sun.mail classes.  And if this used to work, what exactly did you change recently?